# Python Telegram bot send message with buttons

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

i'd like to send a message through telegram bot with buttons. Once button is pressed i need to know which button was that and then change the text that came with the button.

I've almost found out how to do things separately but i can't unite them. To send a message with buttons i need either to write /start or have to press a menu button. I need those buttons to appear after the message without user having to press anything.

This is a script that i've found in the official description with added functions to send a message

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pylint: disable=unused-argument, wrong-import-position
# This program is dedicated to the public domain under the CC0 license.

"""
Basic example for a bot that uses inline keyboards. For an in-depth explanation, check out
 https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/InlineKeyboard-Example.
"""
import logging
import asyncio

from telegram import __version__ as TG_VER

try:
    from telegram import __version_info__
except ImportError:
    __version_info__ = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)  # type: ignore[assignment]

if __version_info__ < (20, 0, 0, "alpha", 1):
    raise RuntimeError(
        f"This example is not compatible with your current PTB version {TG_VER}. To view the "
        f"{TG_VER} version of this example, "
        f"visit https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v{TG_VER}/examples.html"
    )
from telegram import Bot, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, Application, CallbackQueryHandler, CommandHandler, ContextTypes

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO
)
# set higher logging level for httpx to avoid all GET and POST requests being logged
logging.getLogger("httpx").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    """Sends a message with three inline buttons attached."""
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data="1"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data="2"),
        ],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data="3")],
    ]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    await update.message.reply_text("Please choose:", reply_markup=reply_markup)


async def button(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    await query.answer()

    await query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data}")


async def help_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    """Displays info on how to use the bot."""
    await update.message.reply_text("Use /start to test this bot.")

# using telegram.Bot
async def send(chat, msg):
    await Bot('<TOKEN>').sendMessage(chat_id=chat, text=msg)

# using ApplicationBuilder
async def send_more(chat, msg):
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token('<TOKEN>').build()
    await application.bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat, text=msg)

def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # Create the Application and pass it your bot's token.
    application = Application.builder().token("<TOKEN>").build()
    
    
    # asyncio.run(send_more('<CHAT_ID>', 'Hello there!'))
    
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))

    asyncio.run(send('<CHAT_ID>', 'Hello there!'))
    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
    application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

<<< EDIT >>>

The new code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# pylint: disable=unused-argument, wrong-import-position
# This program is dedicated to the public domain under the CC0 license.

"""
Basic example for a bot that uses inline keyboards. For an in-depth explanation, check out
 https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/InlineKeyboard-Example.
"""
import logging

from telegram import __version__ as TG_VER

try:
    from telegram import __version_info__
except ImportError:
    __version_info__ = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0)  # type: ignore[assignment]

if __version_info__ < (20, 0, 0, "alpha", 1):
    raise RuntimeError(
        f"This example is not compatible with your current PTB version {TG_VER}. To view the "
        f"{TG_VER} version of this example, "
        f"visit https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v{TG_VER}/examples.html"
    )
from telegram import Bot, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, Application, CallbackQueryHandler, CommandHandler, ContextTypes

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO
)
# set higher logging level for httpx to avoid all GET and POST requests being logged
logging.getLogger("httpx").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

prolong_1y = 0
prolong_2y = 0
noprolong = 0

async def button(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
    query = update.callback_query

    # CallbackQueries need to be answered, even if no notification to the user is needed
    # Some clients may have trouble otherwise. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery
    await query.answer()

    global prolong_1y, prolong_2y, noprolong

    if "prolong_1y" in query:
        prolong_1y = 1
        prolong_2y = 0
        noprolong = 0
    elif "prolong_2y" in query:
        prolong_1y = 0
        prolong_2y = 1
        noprolong = 0
    elif "noprolong" in query:
        prolong_1y = 0
        prolong_2y = 0
        noprolong = 1
        
    await query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data}")

    print(f"prolong_1y => {prolong_1y}, prolong_2y => {prolong_2y} and noprolong => {noprolong}")
    
# using telegram.Bot
async def send(chat, msg, reply_markup):
    await Bot('<TOKEN>').sendMessage(chat_id=chat, text=msg, reply_markup=reply_markup)

async def post_init(application: Application) -> None:
    """Sends a message with three inline buttons attached."""
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data="prolong_1y"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data="prolong_2y"),
        ],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data="noprolong")],
    ]
    
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    await send('<CHAT_ID>', 'Hello there!', reply_markup)
    
def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # Create the Application and pass it your bot's token.
    application = Application.builder().token("<TOKEN>").post_init(post_init).build()

    application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
    application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error that i receive after pressing on either Choice button:

```
2023-07-19 13:50:13,278 - apscheduler.scheduler - INFO - Scheduler started
2023-07-19 13:50:13,278 - telegram.ext.Application - INFO - Application started
2023-07-19 13:50:16,557 - telegram.ext.Application - ERROR - No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin2/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py", line 1173, in process_update
    await coroutine
  File "/home/admin2/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/ext/_basehandler.py", line 141, in handle_update
    return await self.callback(update, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/media/smb_general/Адміністрування/Source/ElReports/elreports/inlinekeyboard.py", line 50, in button
    if "prolong_1y" in query:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/admin2/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/telegram/_telegramobject.py", line 247, in __getitem__
    return getattr(self, item)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: attribute name must be string, not 'int'
```

<<< EDIT 2 >>>

Silly me, changed query to query.data now everything works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to attach buttons to the message sent in `send`, you can just use the [corresponding parameter of `send_message`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_message.params.reply_markup) for that. Not that [`message.reply_text`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.reply_text) as used in `start` is just a shortcut for that method.

Moreover, you don't need to manually initialize a bot in `send` and to manually run that method via `asyncio.run`. I recommend to instead make use of [`post_init`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.applicationbuilder.html#telegram.ext.ApplicationBuilder.post_init) which allows to run a custom logic as part of the startup logic of `application.run_polling`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing in the right direction. I'm failing to receive the data. It gives me an error. I've updated the first message.

Comment: Silly mistake on my part, changed query to query.data now everything works!

Comment: How do i stop it afterwards? I've tried to put after application.run_polling few options but it didn't work: application.stop(), application.shutdown(), stop(), shutdown()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76724555/10606962