# how to use send_message() in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

i want to send a message to user, without waiting for user triggered my bot. using send_message(), i've been read the documentation but i'm not really understand. Here's my code

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from telegram.ext import *
from telegram import InputFile, Bot
import os
import re

command = ['start']

load_dotenv()

tokenize = os.getenv("TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN")

async def start_commmand(update, context):
    umsg = update.message
    await umsg.reply_text("Welcome, i'll help u with ur schedule")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = Application.builder().token(tokenize).build()

    application.add_handler(CommandHandler(command[0], start_commmand))

    # Run bot
    application.run_polling(1.0)
```

i tried to send a message to bot user using send_mesage(), i hope it's send a message without waiting any message from user. because i'm not really understand after read the documentation, i don't know how to do it

Comment: Please limit your code to just the issue. There is a lot of timing logic, but you're asking on how to send without waiting, please create a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Ostone0s answer I'd like to point out that you don't need the [`Application`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.application.html) class at all to send a message. That class is intended to be used when you actually want to handle updates. For just making plain calls to the Bot API, you can directly use the [`Bot`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot) class. This is also showcased in the PTB [wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API).

---

Dicslaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: um, can u provide me an example?

Comment: Pleake click on the links that I provided and read the content. You'll find an example.

Comment: yes, i've been clicked it and it's works perfectly. thank u sm for ur help

Answer (score 1):

Sending messages usually goes through a [handler](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.handlers-tree.html), you should use those if you can.

That said, of course you can send messages, the `application` is sort of your bot.

As an example, imagine you want to send yourself a message if you start your bot, this can be done by adding a [`post_init`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.post_init) callback, that will run once when you call [`run_polling`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.run_polling):

```py
async def send_start_message(self):
    await self.bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, 'Hello World')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    application = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).build()
    application.post_init = send_start_message

    application.run_polling(1.0)
```

So in this example 'Hello World' will be send to `CHAT_ID` once, on start-up.

Answer (score 0):

So a nice way to do it is how the wiki of @CallMeStag shows.
Since we can't edit that answer, here is a snippet.

```py
import asyncio
import telegram


async def main():
    #That is the easiest way to initiate and send a message.
    bot = telegram.Bot("TOKEN")
    async with bot:
        print(await bot.get_me())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I've casted my vote to that person's answer. But found worthy to set an easy and nice way here.